# How to automatically reset a countdown?

Tags: javascript

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Dec 30, 2019 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

How to reset countdown for every year? How to make year dynamic in the `var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2021 15:37:25").getTime();` so that you don't need to edit the .js file for every new year?

Once it expires in 2019 it starts over and starts counting for 2020 Dec 30 and so on?

Comment: When distance is 0, you can increment `countdownDate`'s year up by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just dynamically get the year based on today's date:

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
dt = new Date();
year = dt.getFullYear();
var countDownDate = new Date(year,11,30,15,37,25).getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Updated the month to account for zero-base

Answer (score 1):

You can use *Date.getFullYear()* method to get the current year and use it to build your `countDownDate`.

```
var year = new Date().getFullYear();
var countDownDate = new Date("Dec 30, " + year + " 15:37:25").getTime();
```